# I want to get swagger json from a unit test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger

My application is a simple spring application. It doesn't have any web-inf folder, or any xml files. It is not a boot application also. I want to run a junit test to get the swagger JSON by hitting /v2/api-docs. But I am not able to run the test class. It gives the error

> Application context cannot be created.

I gave the annotations to the test class like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
```

How can i get the swagger JSON without using any boot dependencies?

Comment: please provide the stack trace when the unit test fails

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mockAppConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'wac'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}